# Wordpress - can't install plugins after server reboot

Tags: linux, centos, wordpress

I'm running a CentOS server which I had to reboot.

However, after the reboot I found myself unable to install wordpress plugins via its admin control panel, as I'm getting a 'failed to connect' message:

[image: wordpress install new plugins page screenshot]

This is strange since the the same configuration worked before the reboot.

Any ideas on what can be the problem?

Comment: Could you connect to the server via ssh and give us the output for the following commands: `iptables -L -v -n`, `chkconfig --list` and `netstat -an`? Make sure you do this with the appropriate rights (sudo/su)

Comment: Thank you. I ran these commands, but isn't it a little problematic - security wise - to upload the output to here as they include our IP addresses? Also, the outputs of the last 2 commands are very long. What do you say?

Comment: Filter out the IPs if you want, no problem. In `chkconfig --list` look for a line with FTP. In `netstat` look for lines containing ftp, 20 or 21.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep ftp`?

Comment: The `chkconfig --list`  output that has  ftp in it is this: `vsftpd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off`. `netstat`'s output doesn't give me anything containingftp, 20 or 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vsftpd 0:off 1:off 2:off 3:off 4:off 5:off 6:off
```

It means that `vsftpd` is not starting at boot. Execute the following commands as root:

```
/etc/init.d/vsftpd start
chkconfig vsftpd on
```

Comment: Thank you, That solved the problem! Do you have an idea what we could do to avoid this in the future?

Comment: `chkconfig vsftpd on` already makes it is starting at boot.